# Maintaining search and sort state across paginated results in web application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a web application where users can search for data and paginate through the results. I've implemented search functionality, allowing users to search for specific data and sorting functionality to sort the results based on certain criteria.

However, I'm facing two main issues:

Search State Persistence: When users navigate to the next page of results, the search query gets reset, and they lose the search context. How can I ensure that the search query persists across pagination so that users can continue browsing results based on their original search?

Sorting State Issue: Additionally, although sorting works fine on the first page of results, when users navigate to subsequent pages, the sorting seems to reset, and the results are not consistently sorted as expected. How can I maintain the sorting state across all pages of results?

I've checked my code thoroughly, but I'm unable to identify the exact issue causing these problems. Could someone please provide insights or suggestions on how to address these issues and ensure a seamless user experience with search and sorting functionality across paginated results?

adminUserList.php

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['sort_order'])) {
    $_SESSION['sort_order'] = ''; // Set default sort order if not set
}

// Store sorting order in session
if (isset($_POST['sort_order'])) {
    $_SESSION['sort_order'] = $_POST['sort_order'];
var_dump($_SESSION);
}

$limit = 5;
$searchValue = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';
$sortOrder = isset($_POST['sort_order']) ? $_POST['sort_order'] : '';

$page = isset($_POST["page_no"]) ? $_POST["page_no"] : 1;
$sno = ($page - 1) * $limit + 1;

if ($searchValue !== "") {
    $result = $database->searchUser($searchValue, (int)$limit);
    $total_record = $database->getTotalRecords(['f_name'], $searchValue);
    $total_page = ceil($total_record / $limit);
    echo $twig->render('adminUserList.twig', ['result' => $result, 'total_page' => $total_page, 'current_page' => $page, 'sno' => $sno, 'searchValue' => $searchValue, 'email' => $email, 'sortOrder' => $_SESSION['sort_order']]);
} elseif ($_SESSION['sort_order']) {
    $result = $database->getUsersSorted($_SESSION['sort_order'], $limit); // Corrected 
    $total_record = $database->getTotalRecords();
    $total_page = ceil($total_record / $limit);
    echo $twig->render('adminUserList.twig', ['result' => $result, 'total_page' => $total_page, 'current_page' => $page, 'sno' => $sno, 'email' => $email, 'sortOrder' => $_SESSION['sort_order']]);
} else {
    // Handle case when neither search nor sorting is applied
    $result = $database->selectAllUser($limit, $page);
    $total_record = $database->getTotalRecords();
    $total_page = ceil($total_record / $limit);
```

admin.js file for handel ajax

```
    // Function to load table data
    function loadTable(page = 1, fn) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "adminUserList.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                page_no: page,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#table-data").html(data);
                fn?.();
            }
        });
    }
   
    // Search code
    function loadSearch(page = 1,oder) {
        var search_term = $("#searchInput").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "adminUserList.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                search: search_term,
                page_no: page,
                sortOrder:oder,

            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#table-data").html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    // Trigger search on keyup
    $(document).on("keyup", "#searchInput", function () {
        loadSearch();
    });

    // Code for pagination search
    $(document).on("click", ".page-item a", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(page_id)
        loadSearch(page_id);
    });

    // Sorting code
    $(document).on("change", "#sort-order", function () {
        var sortOrder = $(this).val();
        sortTable(sortOrder);
    });

    // Function to sort table
    function sortTable(order) {
        console.log(order);
        var page_id = $(".pagination .active").find("a").attr("id");
        console.log(page_id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "adminUserList.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                page_no: page_id,
                sort_order: order
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#table-data").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

twig file

```
                  <select id="sort-order" class="btn btn-secondary">
                <option value="ASC">Ascending</option>
                        <option value="DESC">Descending</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th scope='col'>Email-Id</th>
                <th scope='col'>Phone-No</th>
                {% if result is not empty %}
                    {% for row in result %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ sno }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row['f_name'] }} {{ row['l_name'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row['email'] }}</td>
                            <
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-eid='{{ row['uid'] }}'>view</button>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-id='{{ row['uid'] }}'>Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {% set sno = sno + 1 %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="8">
                            <h2>No Records Found</h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- Pagination controls -->
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if total_page > 0 %}
            {% for page_num in 1..total_page %}
                {% if searchValue != "" %}
                    <li class='Search-item {% if page_num == current_page %}active{% endif %}'>
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_num }}&search={{ searchValue }}" id="{{ page_num }}">
                            {{ page_num }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class='page-item {% if page_num == current_page %}active{% endif %}'>
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_num }}" id="{{ page_num }}">
                            {{ page_num }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <span class="page-link">
                    No Records Found
                </span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: When you debug, what specific functionality in the code shown is invoked when navigating to the next page of records?  What specific part of the code shown makes that request, and how does it include the search/sort/etc. information needed?

Comment: keep the search and sort criteria  in url  like `base_url?q=test?page=1` if you use post keep mentioned data in request. then each time process the data according  to the page and criteria passed to backend.

Comment: You can replace something like `isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';` with `$_POST['search'] ?? ''` since PHP 7.0. See: [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce).

Comment: Your `searchUser($search, $limit)` method doesn't have an offset to tell it where to start when you're on a page other than page 1. See: [MySQL LIMIT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-basics/mysql-limit/). You seem to use the variable named `$sno` for this. Why such a weird name?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of not having "Search State Persistence" arises because adminUserList.php is apparently initially posted to thus you use $_POST to get the params, but then your generated pagination are just anchor tags, where you'd need to use $_GET to get at the params, which you dont have.

There are at least two ways to correct the issue:

(1) Modify your page that initially posts to adminUserList and make it pass the params on the url itself. Then in adminUserList.php change each $_POST to $_GET.

(2) The 2nd way is to modify adminUserList.php so that it can handle both post and get type params.